# Spaces in XML element to show in HTML control

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I am using C# 3.5.  I have an XML string that I pass to XslCompiledTransform object.  I then display the output in a WebBrowser.  All is working great except that the XML elements contain extra spaces which I need to display in the WinForms HTML browser.  I can't use any javascript in the html.  Here is a sample XML element:

```
<myelement>Here is where           extra spaces need to be retained</myelement>
```

I tried replacing the string " " with `"&nbsp;"`but that made the xml that the XslCompiledTransform object used to transform invalid (the XML is invalid).  Then I tried replacing " " with `"&amp;nbsp"` but then the text `&amp;nbsp;` appeared in my html instead of a space.  How can I get the extra spaces to appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
xml:space="preserve"
```

to your xsl stylesheet or your input doc.

[Here's a thorough guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468566.aspx) to whitespace handling in XSLT.

EDIT:

To retain white space in the rendered HTML, use css style `white-space:pre` on the element in which you want to preserve white-space.

Comment: The spaces are retained but HTML won't display extra spaces.  They need to be rewritten as the nbsp; so HTML displays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is an entity in the XHTML DTD, whose actual value is the character `&#xA0;`.

**Therefore, you need to replace every space with `&#xA0;`.**

As simple as:

```
translate(., ' ', '&#xA;')
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="ascii"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <p>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '&#xA0;')"/>
     </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<myelement>Here is where           extra spaces need to be retained</myelement>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<p>Here&#160;is&#160;where&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;extra&#160;spaces&#160;need&#160;to&#160;be&#160;retained</p>
```

**and it is displayed in the browser as**:

Here is where           extra spaces need to be retained

Comment: Non-breaking spaces are different to normal spaces because, as advertised, they will not cause a line break and can cause layout issues. Misused and best avoided IMO.

Comment: @spender, Yes, I tend to believe so. However, the OP wants to do it this way and has asked for specific XSLT help.

Comment: @spender, Good, this is why I prefix comments with the id of the recepient -- to avoid such misunderstandings.